# Expression for quadratic variation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

I read a book and don't understand the following:

Let $X$ be a continuous local martingale and is uniformly bounded. Let $\langle X \rangle^{(n)}_t = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (X_{t \wedge t^n_k}- X_{t \wedge t^n_{k-1}})^2,$ where $t^n_k = k2^{-n}$.

We then define a process $M^{(n)}$ by  $M^{(n)}_t = \frac{1}{2} ( X^2_t - \langle X \rangle^{(n)}_t )$ and let $M^{(n)}_{\infty} = \lim_{t \to \infty} M^{(n)}_t$. By telescoping the sum, we get $$M^{(n)}_t = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} X_{t^{n}_{k-1}} (X_{t \wedge t^n_k}- X_{t \wedge t^n_{k-1}}).$$ Then it claims that

> $$ \forall n >m, \quad M^{(n)}_{\infty} - M^{(m)}_{\infty} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \big( X_{j 2^{-n}} - X_{{\lfloor{j2^{m-n}}\rfloor}2^{-m}} \big) \big( X_{(j+1) 2^{-n}} -  X_{j 2^{-n}} \big). $$

Can someone please explain this to me?

I know how to show that 
$$ \quad M^{(n)}_{\infty}= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  X_{j 2^{-n}} \big( X_{(j+1) 2^{-n}} -  X_{j 2^{-n}} \big). $$ The expression involving $m$ is what bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really helpful to draw a picture. For fixed $m<n$, the partition $$\Pi^m := \left\{\frac{1}{2^m} < \frac{2}{2^m} < \ldots < \frac{k}{2^m} < \ldots \right\}$$ is coarser than the partition

$$\Pi^n := \left\{\frac{1}{2^n} < \frac{2}{2^n} < \ldots < \frac{k}{2^n} < \ldots \right\}.$$ Now, since we are interested in the difference $M^{(n)}-M^{(m)}$, we would like to rewrite the definition of $M_t^{(m)}$ using the partition $\Pi^n$, i.e. to write

$$M_t^{(m)}  =\sum_j Y_j (X_{t \wedge t_{j}^n}-X_{t \wedge t_{j-1}^n})$$

for some random variables $Y_j$. It remains to determine $Y_j$. To this end, we note that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find a (unique) $j=j(k) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$t_k^m = k \frac{1}{2^m} = j \frac{1}{2^n} = t_j^n,$$

namely,

$$j(k) = k 2^{n-m}. \tag{1}$$

Now

$$\begin{align*} M_t^{(m)} &= \sum_{j \geq 1} Y_j (X_{t \wedge t_{j}^n}-X_{t \wedge t_{j-1}^n}) \\ &= \sum_{k \geq 1} \sum_{j=j(k-1)}^{j(k)-1} Y_j (X_{t \wedge t_{j+1}^n}-X_{t \wedge t_{j}^n}) \\ &= \sum_{k \geq 1} \tilde{Y}_k \underbrace{\sum_{j=j(k-1)}^{j(k)-1} (X_{t \wedge t_{j+1}^n}-X_{t \wedge t_{j}^n})}_{X_{t \wedge t_{j(k)}^n}-X_{t \wedge t_{j(k-1)}^n} = X_{t \wedge t_{k}^m}-X_{t \wedge t_{k-1}^m}} \end{align*}$$

if we choose $Y_j = \tilde{Y}_k$ for all $j(k-1) \leq j \leq j(k)-1$. Comparing this expression with the definition of $M_t^{(m)}$, we find

$$\tilde{Y}_k = X_{t \wedge t_{k-1}^m}.$$

Note that $Y_j = \tilde{Y}_{k(j)}$ with $k=k(j) $ such that $j(k-1) \leq j \leq j(k)-1$, i.e. for each $j$ we have to find $k(j)$ such that $j \in \left[ (k(j)-1) 2^{n-m}, k(j) 2^{n-m}-1 \right]$. Obviously,

$$k(j) = \lfloor 2^{m-n}j \rfloor.$$

Consequently,

$$Y_j = X_{t \wedge t_{\lfloor 2^{m-n} j \rfloor-1}^m}.$$

Comment: I don't understand the third step: How can we handle the double summation? $X_{t \wedge t_k^m} - X_{t \wedge \tau_{k-1}^m} = \sum_{j=(k-1)2^{-m+n}+1}^{k 2^{-m+n}} ( X_{t \wedge t_j^n} - X_{t \wedge t_{j-1}^n}) $

gives

$ M_t^{(m)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \sum_{j=(k-1)2^{-m+n}+1}^{k 2^{-m+n}} X_{t^m_{k-1}} ( X_{t \wedge t_j^n} - X_{t \wedge t_{j-1}^n}) $

Comment: @Richard See my edited answer. It's still a mess, sorry - as I wrote: it really helps a lot to draw a picture. Basically, it's all about finding corresponding intervals in the coarser/finer partition.

Comment: I also don't understand a statement that says that if $T_N = \inf \{ t \geq 0 : |X_t| >N \}$, then $ \langle X^{T_{N+1}} \rangle^{(n)}_t - \langle X^{T_{N}} \rangle^{(n)}_t \geq 0$, for $t > T_N$. Should we consider the different orderings of $T_N < T_{N+1} , t$ and $t^k_n$?

Comment: @Richard Have to think about it. (And it might be better to ask a new question; this variation stuff is always so lengthy...)

Comment: I suppose that there might be a typo: it is true if it is changed to ${\langle X^{T_{N+1}} \rangle}_t - {\langle X^{T_{N}} \rangle}_t \geq 0.$ Interpreting the limit in a.s. sense, ${\langle X^{T_{N+1}} \rangle}_t - {\langle X^{T_{N}} \rangle}_t = \lim_{n \to \infty} [{\langle X^{T_{N+1}} \rangle}^{(n)}_t - {\langle X^{T_{N}} \rangle}^{(n)}_t] =   \lim_{n \to \infty} [{\langle X \rangle}^{(n)}_{t \wedge T_{N+1}} - {\langle X \rangle}^{(n)}_{t \wedge T_{N}}] = $

Comment: $=\lim_{n \to \infty} [{\langle X \rangle}^{(n)}_{2^{-n} \lfloor 2^n(t \wedge T_{N+1}) \rfloor} - {\langle X \rangle}^{(n)}_{2^{-n} \lfloor 2^n(t \wedge T_{N}) \rfloor} ] \geq 0. $

Comment: Is my argument correct?

Comment: @Richard Yeah, should be correct. (I was confused because of the jumps, but since you consider continuous martingales you don't have any jumps.)